# grails 3 mail plugin html view giving error when called from Bootstrap or Job

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

I have a service that uses grails mail plugin

```
@Transactional
@Slf4j
class ExpireAlertService {
    def mailService
...
...
    void sendExpiryMails() {

        def list = SomeDomain.list()
        list.each {
            log.debug('Sending Mail {}', it.id)

            mailService.sendMail {
                to 'to@somedomain.com'
                from 'sender@mydomain.com'
                subject "Expiry Alert !!!"
                html view: "/email/expiry", model: [
                        id              : id,
                        ...

                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the email template is in `grails-app/view/email/expiry.gsp`. When this service is injected into a controller and called from some action, it works as expected and mail is sent. But when the same service is injected in `Bootstrap.groovy` or a scheduled job, I get this exception when it runs

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3042) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1075) ~[springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:80) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer$PageRenderRequestCreator.createInstance(MailMessageContentRenderer.groovy:198) ~[mail-2.0.0.RC4.jar:na]
    at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer$PageRenderRequestCreator$createInstance.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer$RenderEnvironment.init(MailMessageContentRenderer.groovy:147) ~[mail-2.0.0.RC4.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426) ~[springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer$RenderEnvironment.with(MailMessageContentRenderer.groovy:178) ~[mail-2.0.0.RC4.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426) ~[springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:151) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:91) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer.render(MailMessageContentRenderer.groovy:63) ~[mail-2.0.0.RC4.jar:na]
    at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer$render.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageBuilder.doRender(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:277) ~[mail-2.0.0.RC4.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426) ~[springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageBuilder.html(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:295) ~[mail-2.0.0.RC4.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426) ~[springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at ExpireAlertService$__tt__sendExpiryMails_closure4$_closure7.doCall(ExpireAlertService.groovy:45) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
```

The exception originates at the `html view:"/email/expiry"` line. Is there anything that I need to do to resolve gsp views from non controller use cases ?

I am using grails 3.1.1 and mail plugin `org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC4`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens when your serverUrl is not set. In my Bootstrap.groovy, I use this:

```
def grailsApplication // injected
...
LinkGenerator grailsLinkGenerator = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean("grailsLinkGenerator")
grailsLinkGenerator.configuredServerBaseURL ?: grailsApplication.config.grails.serverUrl
```

This propagates the serverUrl configured on a per-environment basis without having to set a global one.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it but I ended up configuring serverURL as I would need it for other cases as well.

Comment: Glad this worked for you as well. To be sure, I also set the serverUrl variables, but I use different ones for development, testing, and production.